# How to purge all tabs for spaces in all C files in a directory?

Tags: vim, find

I'm trying to fix the style in a directory of about 60 `.c` and `.h` files.  This can be taken in steps (e.g. I don't have to figure out find and vim script syntax at the same time), but ultimately I want to do something like this:

```
find . -name '*.[ch]' -exec vim "{} +'set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab | wq'" \;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name '*.[ch]' -exec vim +"set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab | retab | wq" {} \;
```

Wow.  The linux command line is incredible.

Answer (score 1):

While using vim might work, a better alternative would be a tool designed for formatting source code.

- [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net)
- [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/)
- [GNU Indent](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/manual/indent.html)
- [clang-format](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) - for Mac users